# How to use a value that is stored in a db table in a msgbox?

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I'm trying to insert a record (ID, YEAR, MONTH, VALUE) in the database, using an excel file, but if that record exists (with the same or different value) it should pop up a message saying that it already exists and if the user would like to replace it. How can I use the VALUE stored in the db, that I would like (or not) to replace, on the message box?

```
(...)
If has_permission Then

   Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
   Set rsUpdate = New ADODB.Recordset

   conn.Open sConnString
   Set rsUpdate = conn.Execute("SELECT ID FROM dbo.VALORES WHERE ID = " & sID & " AND YEAR = " & sYEAR & " AND MONTH = " & sMONTH & ";")

   If Not rsUpdate.EOF And Not rsUpdate.BOF Then

        result_msgbox = MsgBox("This record already exists with the value _DB.VALUE HERE_ . Would you like to replace it?", vbYesNo)
        If result_msgbox = 6 Then

            Set rsUpdate = conn.Execute("UPDATE dbo.VALORES SET VALUE = " & sVALUE & " WHERE ID = " & sID & " AND YEAR = " & sYEAR & " AND MONTH = " & sMONTH & ";")
            .Cells(iRowNo, 6).Value = "Record replaced"
        End If

GoTo linha_processada

   End If
(...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I've managed to find a solution for my problem by using **rsUpdate.Fields(i).Value**.

```
If has_permission Then
   Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
   Set rsUpdate = New ADODB.Recordset
   conn.Open sConnString
   Set rsUpdate = conn.Execute("SELECT ID, VALUE FROM dbo.VALORES WHERE ID = " & sID & " AND YEAR = " & sYEAR & " AND MONTH = " & sMONTH & ";")
   If Not rsUpdate.EOF And Not rsUpdate.BOF Then
        result_msgbox = MsgBox("This record already exists with the value " & rsUpdate.Fields(2).Value & " . Would you like to replace it?", vbYesNo)
        If result_msgbox = 6 Then
            Set rsUpdate = conn.Execute("UPDATE dbo.VALORES SET VALUE = " & sVALUE & " WHERE ID = " & sID & " AND YEAR = " & sYEAR & " AND MONTH = " & sMONTH & ";")
            .Cells(iRowNo, 6).Value = "Record replaced"
        End If
GoTo linha_processada
   End If
```

Answer (score 0):

add **value on select statement**. then retrieve later. try this. its not tested

```
If has_permission Then
   Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
   Set rsUpdate = New ADODB.Recordset
   conn.Open sConnString
   Set rsUpdate = conn.Execute("SELECT ID, Value FROM dbo.VALORES WHERE ID = " & sID & " AND YEAR = " & sYEAR & " AND MONTH = " & sMONTH & ";")
   If Not rsUpdate.EOF And Not rsUpdate.BOF Then
        result_msgbox = MsgBox("This record already exists with the value " & rsUpdate.Value  & "  . Would you like to replace it?", vbYesNo)
        If result_msgbox = 6 Then
            Set rsUpdate = conn.Execute("UPDATE dbo.VALORES SET VALUE = " & sVALUE & " WHERE ID = " & sID & " AND YEAR = " & sYEAR & " AND MONTH = " & sMONTH & ";")
            .Cells(iRowNo, 6).Value = "Record replaced"
        End If
GoTo linha_processada
   End If
```

Comment: i do not see any insert in above code so how its going to add?

Comment: tried your suggestion but it didn't work. It gave me error: Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: the insert comes after with this code
```
conn.Execute "insert into dbo.VALORES (ID, YEAR, MONTH, VALUE) values ('" & sID & "', '" & sYEAR & "', '" & sMONTH & "'', '" & sVALUE & "')"
```